# Unable to use the edit functionality of contacts using CNContactViewController in swift

Tags: swift, cncontactviewcontroller

I am working with ContactUI in swift.I am listing the contacts using this code

```
    let contactPickerViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPickerViewController.delegate = self
    present(contactPickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When i select a specific screen, the screen with details of selected contact pops up. But the "Edit" option is not available on this screen. Now I want to know how to activate the built-in edit functionality in this case.

Comment: No. I am just using the above mentioned lines of code on a button click. Everything is getting displayed including list of contacts, details of specific contact etc on its own except the edit functionality is not present there.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do this you have to fetch the contact change it inside your app and then save it again

Comment: okay. Thank you for the guidance.